# How to access elements in navbar when it gets collapsed?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here I have a navbar that you can see by running the snippet code which there are some links in it and it's looking good. I have set a `margin-right` of `50px` to the `first-child` of the `ul` tag to make it look a little better and you can see when we make the browser window smaller in terms of width, navbar gets collapsed. So far there is no problem. But when we click on hamburger icon we can see that the first element is in front of the others and does not look good.

So how can I access that element to set its `margin-right` attribute to a proper value when it's in collapse mode?

Thank you.

```css
nav div ul li:first-child{
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.collapse {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">     
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-right ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">product<a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove `margin-right` when the navbar collapsed?

Comment: Use media query it work for all the viewport as you want.

Comment: @Aman yes, I want to do that

Answer (score 2):

You would use a CSS selector like:

```
.collapse:not.show div ul li:first-child{
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/fndehceCk7)